# How to transform the index in a integer in a forall loop?

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TYPE o_A AS OBJECT (A1 VARCHAR2 (4000));

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_A IS TABLE OF o_A;

CREATE TABLE table_o_A
(
      oA_id                INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
      oA                   o_A,
      PRIMARY KEY (oA_id)
    );
```

I would to add the lines of a t_A in the table_oA.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE aa (query_result    t_A)
is
    v_i   INTEGER;
begin
    SELECT MAX (oA_id)
          INTO v_i
          FROM table_o_A;
          
    FORALL i IN INDICES OF query_result
            INSERT INTO table_o_A(
                            oA_id,
                            oA)
                 VALUES ( v_i+i, query_result (i));
                 
end;
```

> [Error] Compilation (887: 26): PLS-00430: FORALL iteration variable I is not allowed in this context

I thinks it doesn't work because i isn't an integer.
I could use a for loop and use a real integer but it make a switch between the pl/sql and sql context.
How do I do that with the ForAll loop?

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=48f7175db930b9abd1e416ae3faba313)

[solution from Alex Poole](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b159c2b5e9b554bf174191b57c92c99e)

Comment: Why are you overriding the generated-by-default identity value?

Comment: @AlexPoole What do you mean

Comment: Your `oA_id` column is a sequence-backed identity, so by default if you don't specify the `oA_id` value it will be auto-assigned. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=22e6d7bab2fd9b8fe432ef8eb823d75b). Mixing auto- and manually-assigned values will cause clashes. But as this is somewhat contrived I don't know if you're doing that on purpose to reflect some real need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thinks it doesn't work because i isn't an integer.

No, this is a restriction on the `forall` syntax; [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/FORALL-statement.html), your `i` index is (emphasis added):

> Name for the implicitly declared integer variable that is local to the FORALL statement. Statements outside the FORALL statement cannot reference *index*. Statements inside the FORALL statement can reference *index* as an index variable, **but cannot use it in expressions** or change its value. After the FORALL statement runs, index is undefined.

---

Your `oA_id` is a sequence-backed identity column - albeit only default, not always - so you don't have to specify a value. Unless you're already mixing manual and auto-assigned ID values, the max you get will be compatible with the sequence value (there may be gaps, of course); but having set ID values manually, the sequence will then be out of step and you'd get clashes from auto-assigned values, unless it was reset to the current limit.

Unless you have a good reason to mix manual and auto, you can simplify what you are doing to just:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE a (query_result    t_A)
is
begin
    FORALL i IN INDICES OF query_result
            INSERT INTO table_o_A(oA)
                 VALUES (query_result (i));
end;
/
```

... and *only* provide the objects in the insert statement.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=22e6d7bab2fd9b8fe432ef8eb823d75b)